# Expected primary-expression before '[' token

Tags: c++, c, compilacion

Hola soy nuevo en programacion y estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi escuela donde tengo que usar funciones, estructuras, bucles y demas, me acabo de topar con este problema, ya intente varias maneras, incluso escribir de nuevo el codigo pero todavia no he llegado a una solucion

Alguien sabe porque me aparece este error?
Los errores estan desde las lineas 87-91 y de 131-136
Habia echo un programa similar pero ahora no me esta dejando compilar, pienso debe de ser por algo de las estructuras

No se si es la estructura correcta la que estoy llevando, espero su respuesta y muchas gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
 
 //Prototipos de funciones
 void opcionMenu();
 //int opcmenuexterior, int opcmenumaestro,int opcmenualumno,int x, int g,int i,alumnos[],datosmaestro[]
 
 //Variables globales
 int opcmenuexterior,opcmenumaestro, opcmenualumno,x,g,i;
 
 //Estructuras
 
 typedef struct datos{
    char nombre[30];
    char apellido[30];
    char turno[30];     
 }registro;
 
 typedef struct nino{
    char materia[30];
    char maestroinside[30];
    int grado;
    char grupo[30];
    int calificacion;
    struct datos datoalumno;
 }alumnos;
 
 typedef struct datosmaestro{
    char nombremaestro[30];
    char apellidomaestro[30];
    char turnomaestro[30];

 }registromaestro;
 
 typedef struct maestros{
    char materiamaestro[30];
    long cedula;
    char gradomaestro[30];
    char grupomaestro[30];
    long numeromaestro;
    struct datosmaestro maestrodato;
    
    
 }maestro;
 
 int main(){
    opcionMenu();
    // opcmenuexterior,opcmenumaestro, opcmenualumno,x,g,i, alumnos[], datosmaestro[]
    
    
    
    getch();
    return 0; 
 }
 
 
 void opcionMenu(){
    //int opcmenuexterior, int opcmenumaestro, int opcmenualumno,int x,int g,int i, alumnos[], datosmaestro[]  
    
    do{
     
    
    cout<<"\t\n\tBienvenido al sistema escolar...\n\n           Que desea hacer?\n\t 1- Registro\n\t 2- Busqueda\n\t 3- Consulta de la informacion \n\t 4- Salir ";
    cin>>opcmenuexterior;
fflush(stdin);
 switch(opcmenuexterior){
    rewind(stdin);
    case 1: cout<<"\n\tVas a registrar Maestro u Alumno reprobado\n\t 1- Para Alumno---: \n\t 2- Para Maestro---: "; 
    cin>>opcmenumaestro; 
    switch(opcmenumaestro){
            case 1: for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
                
            do{
                
                
                
                
            if(i<15){
            
            if(x==1){
            
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"\n\nDigite su nombre: "; cin.getline(alumnos[i].datoalumno.nombre,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite su apellido : "; cin.getline(alumnos[i].datoalumno.apellido,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite el turno al cual pertenece: "; cin>>(alumnos[i].datoalumno.turno,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite la materia reprobada : "; cin>>(alumnos[i].materia,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite la calificacion que obtuvo: " ; cin>>(alumnos[i].calificacion);
            cout<<
            i++;
            g++;
             cin.ignore(256, '\n'); 
              cout<<"\nQuieres continuar?...\n 1- Si \n 2-No "; cin>>x;
        if(i>=15){ cout<<"\nHas excedido el maximo de boletos a registrar";
        break;
        }
            
            
            
        
        
            
            fflush(stdin);
        
        }else{ break;

  }
        
        
    }

             }while(x==1); cout<<"\n";

    
        
        
        } 
        
        
        case 2: for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        
        do{
            if(i<15){
            
            if(x==1){
            
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"\n\nDigite su nombre: "; cin.getline(datosmaestro[i].nombremaestro,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite su apellido : "; cin.getline(datosmaestro[i].apellidomaestro,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite el turno al cual pertenece: "; cin>>(datosmaestro[i].turnomaestro,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite la materia a ensenar : "; cin>>(maestro[i].materiamaestro,30,'\n');
            cout<<"\nDigite su numero de celular: " ; cin>>(maestro[i].numeromaestro);
            cout<<"\nDigite su numero de cedula: " ; cin>>(maestro[i].cedula);
 
            i++;
            g++;
             cin.ignore(256, '\n'); 
              cout<<"\nQuieres continuar?...\n 1- Si \n 2-No "; cin>>x;
        if(i>=15){ cout<<"\nHas excedido el maximo de boletos a registrar";
        break;
        }
            
            
            
        
        
            
            fflush(stdin);
        
        }else{ break;

  }
        
        
    }

             }while(x==1); cout<<"\n";

    
        
        
        } 
    
        
     }
    
    
 }  
    //bucle
    }while(i=0);
    //bucle
 }
```

Comment: `alumnos` y `datosmaestro` son tipos, y tu los estas usando como si fueran variables. Por eso es que te salen los errores.

Comment: Como se suppone que deberian de ser?

Comment: Crea variables, y usa esas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es bastante redundante, tiene estructuras que no necesitas. La estructura datos esta definida para que contenga datos de los alumnos o de los maestros y por ello no es necesario definir una nueva estructura llamada 'datomaestro'. Los errores que tenías se deben a que no llamabas correctamente a la estructura, además que al querer guardar los datos en la estructura que tenías, realmente lo hacías en una variable y por ello nunca te iban a quedar guardados los registros como un conjunto de datos. Lo que debías hacer era definir cada variable de la estructura como un arreglo, el tamaño del arreglo va a depender de la cantidad de datos que quieras guardar en la estructura.

No inicializaste la variable 'x', y es por ello que cada vez que el código se ejecutara se detendría inesperadamente sin haber completado ninguna función. La variable 'x=1', ya que en tu código otro número que no sea '1' es usado para salir del do while.

Te dejo el código funcionando sin ninguno de los errores que mencionaste, puedes compararlo con tu código actual, y revisar la parte donde pides los datos para guardarlos en las estructuras. No debes olvidar en qué estructura estás guardando los datos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//Prototipos de funciones
void opcionMenu();
//int opcmenuexterior, int opcmenumaestro,int opcmenualumno,int x, int g,int i,alumnos[],datosmaestro[]

//Variables globales
int opcmenuexterior,opcmenumaestro, opcmenualumno,x=1,g,i;

//Estructuras

struct datos {
    char nombre[30];
    char apellido[30];
    char turno[30];
}registro[5];

struct nino {
    char materia[30];
    char maestroinside[30];
    int grado;
    char grupo[30];
    int calificacion;
    struct datos datoalumno;
}alumnos[5];

//Esta Struct es completamente inecesaria
/*struct datosmaestro {
    char nombremaestro[30];
    char apellidomaestro[30];
    char turnomaestro[30];

}registromaestro[5];*/

struct maestros {
    char materiamaestro[30];
    long cedula;
    char gradomaestro[30];
    char grupomaestro[30];
    long numeromaestro;
    struct datos maestrodato;
} maestro[5];

int main() {
    opcionMenu();
    // opcmenuexterior,opcmenumaestro, opcmenualumno,x,g,i, alumnos[], datosmaestro[]
    getch();
    return 0;
}


void opcionMenu() {
    //int opcmenuexterior, int opcmenumaestro, int opcmenualumno,int x,int g,int i, alumnos[], datosmaestro[]

    do {
        cout<<"\t\n\tBienvenido al sistema escolar...\n\n           Que desea hacer?\n\t 1- Registro\n\t 2- Busqueda\n\t 3- Consulta de la informacion \n\t 4- Salir ";
        cin>>opcmenuexterior;
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(opcmenuexterior) {
//            rewind(stdin);
        case 1:
            cout<<"\n\tVas a registrar Maestro u Alumno reprobado\n\t 1- Para Alumno---: \n\t 2- Para Maestro---: ";
            cin>>opcmenumaestro;
            switch(opcmenumaestro) {
            case 1:
                for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {

                    do {
                        if(i<15) {
                            if(x==1) {

                                fflush(stdin);
                                cout<<"\n\nDigite su nombre: ";
                                cin.getline(alumnos[i].datoalumno.nombre,30,'\n');
                                cout<<"\nDigite su apellido : ";
                                cin.getline(alumnos[i].datoalumno.apellido,30,'\n');
                                cout<<"\nDigite el turno al cual pertenece: ";
                                cin>>alumnos[i].datoalumno.turno,30,'\n';
                                cout<<"\nDigite la materia reprobada : ";
                                cin>>alumnos[i].materia,30,'\n';
                                cout<<"\nDigite la calificacion que obtuvo: " ;
                                cin>>alumnos[i].calificacion;
                                cout<<i++;
                                g++;
                                cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                                cout<<"\nQuieres continuar?...\n 1- Si \n 2-No ";
                                cin>>x;
                                if(i>=15) {
                                    cout<<"\nHas excedido el maximo de boletos a registrar";
                                    break;
                                }
                                fflush(stdin);

                            } else {
                                //break;
                                x=2;
                                opcionMenu();
                            }


                        }

                    } while(x==1);
                    cout<<"\n";




                }


            case 2:
                for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {

                    do {
                        if(i<15) {

                            if(x==1) {

                                fflush(stdin);
                                cout<<"\n\nDigite su nombre: ";
                                //cin.getline(alumnos[i].datoalumno.nombre,30,'\n');
                                //cin>>alumnos[i].datoalumno.turno,30,'\n';
                                cin.getline(maestro[i].maestrodato.nombre,30,'\n');
                                cout<<"\nDigite su apellido : ";
                                cin.getline(maestro[i].maestrodato.apellido,30,'\n');
                                cout<<"\nDigite el turno al cual pertenece: ";
                                cin.getline(maestro[i].maestrodato.turno,30,'\n');
                                cout<<"\nDigite la materia a ensenar : ";
                                cin>>maestro[i].materiamaestro,30,'\n';
                                cout<<"\nDigite su numero de celular: " ;
                                cin>>maestro[i].numeromaestro;
                                cout<<"\nDigite su numero de cedula: " ;
                                cin>>maestro[i].cedula;

                                i++;
                                g++;
                                cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                                cout<<"\nQuieres continuar?...\n 1- Si \n 2-No ";
                                cin>>x;
                                if(i>=15) {
                                    cout<<"\nHas excedido el maximo de boletos a registrar";
                                    break;
                                }

                                fflush(stdin);

                            } else {
                                //break;
                                x=1;
                                opcionMenu();

                            }


                        }

                    } while(x==1);
                    cout<<"\n";

                }


            }


        }
        //bucle
    } while(i=0);
    //bucle
}
```

Si te sirvió de ayuda mi respuesta puedes marcarla con el check como la correcta. No dudes en dejar comentarios si tienes alguna duda.